# Reducing the time to locate four XYZ coordinates from a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, logic

Sample CSV file: [sample csv file with force in Y direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2izw.png)

We are trying to four points on a 3D grid stored in a dataframe. Each point has x,y,z values and a corresponding force in the y and z direction. The first point we want is at a given radius and at angle 0, the next point is 180 degrees away from that point, the third point is at the same y,z coordinates as the second, but with the other x value (there are only two possible x values), the last point is at the same y,z point as the first point, but has the other x. The dataframe looks like this:

| Node Number | X Location | Y Location | Z Location | Y Force | Z Force |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 82.916 | -182.25 | -200.32 | 6.95E-02 | 7.11E-03 |
| 2 | 81.542 | 50.54 | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | ... | ... |  |  |  |
| 4 | ... |  |  |  |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |
| 497500 | ... |  |  |  |  |

The dataframe contains 5 columns; X Location (mm), Y Location (mm), and Z Location (mm), Force_y_direction, Force_z_direction. These coordinates are read from a .csv file and stored in a pandas dataframe as such;

```
def link_csv_files():
    # Read xyz coordinates from csv file
    df_x = pd.read_csv('x-data.csv', engine='python')

    create_nodes(df_x, df_y, df_z)

def create_nodes(df_x, df_y, df_z):
    # Copy the common columns into the df_combined dataframe (Node Number, X Location, Y Location, Z Location)
    df_combined['Node Number'] = df_x['Node Number']
    df_combined['X Location (mm)'] = df_x['X Location (mm)']
    df_combined['Y Location (mm)'] = df_x['Y Location (mm)']
    df_combined['Z Location (mm)'] = df_x['Z Location (mm)']

    # Iterate over the columns for the y-directional force
    for column in df_y.columns[4:]:
        # Copy the column values to the combined DataFrame
        df_combined['Y Elastic Strain (mm/mm)'] = df_y[column]

    # Iterate over the columns of the z-directional force
    for column in df_z.columns[4:]:
        # Copy the column values to the combined DataFrame
        df_combined['Z Elastic Strain (mm/mm)'] = df_z[column]
```

There are three .csv files, they all share the same Node Number, and xys locations. The only difference is the rightmost column; one file has the x force, one file has the y force, last file has the z force
[sample csv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETDT3.png)

There are 500,000 points

The points fall on different radius' on a circle, and they are located at every 11.25 degrees around the radius. y is the length, z is the height, and x is the depth. [3D point, y-z view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3uvu.png)

We want to find two sets of points that will be used in an equation: the first set of points have the same depth, but are located 180 degrees apart. The second set of points are at the same y,z locations but on the other side (there are 2 depth values).

The problem is at the moment it takes 11 minutes to find the four points for one radius. We want to reduce this time. We can use any libraries.

This is my current implementation:

```
# Function to find the combination of 4 points
# df_points: The dataframe containing all node locations
# points_arr: An array of every points along 0-180 degrees
def find_point_combinations(df_points, points_arr):
    
    # Array to store the two sets of points.
    voltage = []

    for n in range(0, len(points_arr)):
        point1 = points_arr[n]
        point3 = point1

        #Finding point3 
        for pt in range(0, len(df_points)):
            if df_points['Y Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == -1 * point1[2] and df_points['Z Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == -1 * point1[3]:
                if df_points['X Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == point1[1]:
                    point3 = df_points.loc[pt]
                    break  

        #Finding point4, which is on the other side
        for pt in range(0, len(df_points)):
            if df_points['Y Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == point3[2] and df_points['Z Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == point3[3]:
                if df_points['X Location (mm)'].loc[pt] != point3[1]:
                    point4 = df_points.loc[pt]
                    break

        #Finding point2
        for pt in range(0, len(df_points)):
            if df_points['Y Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == point1[2] and df_points['Z Location (mm)'].loc[pt] == point1[3]:
                if df_points['X Location (mm)'].loc[pt] != point1[1]:
                    point2 = df_points.loc[pt]
                    break

       voltage.append(point1, point2, point3, point4)
       return voltage
```

It uses four for-loops which causes a lot of overhead. I believe this is one reason why the processing time is so high. One set of points results in this output:

```
Node Number                 2.708330e+05
X Location (mm)             1.168100e+02
Y Location (mm)             2.060000e-04
Z Location (mm)             2.958000e+02
X Elastic Strain (mm/mm)             NaN
Y Elastic Strain (mm/mm)    2.420000e-06
Z Elastic Strain (mm/mm)   -5.970000e-07
Error                       4.200000e+00
Angle (deg)                 1.800000e+02
Radius                      2.958000e+02

Name: 15, dtype: float64
Node Number                 90690.000000
X Location (mm)               124.010000
Y Location (mm)               -58.527000
Z Location (mm)               294.240000
X Elastic Strain (mm/mm)             NaN
Y Elastic Strain (mm/mm)        0.000005
Z Elastic Strain (mm/mm)        0.000001
Error                         597.115221
Angle (deg)                   180.000000
Radius                        295.800000

Name: 367794, dtype: float64
Node Number                 2.708330e+05
X Location (mm)             1.168100e+02
Y Location (mm)            -2.060000e-04
Z Location (mm)            -2.958000e+02
X Elastic Strain (mm/mm)             NaN
Y Elastic Strain (mm/mm)    2.420000e-06
Z Elastic Strain (mm/mm)   -5.970000e-07
Error                       4.200000e+00
Angle (deg)                 1.800000e+02
Radius                      2.958000e+02

Name: 15, dtype: float64
Node Number                 90509.000000
X Location (mm)               124.010000
Y Location (mm)                58.527000
Z Location (mm)              -294.240000
X Elastic Strain (mm/mm)             NaN
Y Elastic Strain (mm/mm)        0.000003
Z Elastic Strain (mm/mm)       -0.000001
Error                          58.809755
Angle (deg)                   180.000000
Radius                        295.800000

Name: 3266, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Throw your data into an [RDBMS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), e.g. using [df.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). Index the Y and Z columns. Now your WHERE clause can efficiently find nearby coordinates, without even considering most of those half-million points you keep looping over. Or do a [.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) if you're allergic to tables.

Comment: Can you also provide sample CSVs? Also how fast do you want it compared to your current implementation?

Comment: @ken Would like to have it go from 11.2 minutes to 5-8 minutes. I have updated the question with a sample CSV at the top

Comment: - or less than 5 mins

Comment: Thank you. However, what I requested was not an image, but actual (or parts of) CSV files that could be used for testing and benchmarking. But since your goal was not very high, maybe the way I just posted will be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to meet your needs, but you should first learn the basics of using pandas.

Here is a reimplementation of your function in the pandas style:

```py
def find_point_combinations(df_points, points_arr):
    # Array to store the two sets of points.
    voltage = []

    for n in range(0, len(points_arr)):
        point1 = points_arr[n]

        # Finding point3
        x_matched = df_points["X Location (mm)"] == point1[1]
        y_matched = df_points["Y Location (mm)"] == -point1[2]
        z_matched = df_points["Z Location (mm)"] == -point1[3]
        xyz_matched_points = df_points[x_matched & y_matched & z_matched]
        # If you want to check how many points matched, check the length here.
        assert len(xyz_matched_points) == 1
        point3 = xyz_matched_points.iloc[0]  # Extract the first matched point.

        # Finding point4, which is on the other side
        x_matched = df_points["X Location (mm)"] != point3[1]
        y_matched = df_points["Y Location (mm)"] == point3[2]
        z_matched = df_points["Z Location (mm)"] == point3[3]
        xyz_matched_points = df_points[x_matched & y_matched & z_matched]
        assert len(xyz_matched_points) == 1
        point4 = xyz_matched_points.iloc[0]

        # Finding point2
        x_matched = df_points["X Location (mm)"] != point1[1]
        y_matched = df_points["Y Location (mm)"] == point1[2]
        z_matched = df_points["Z Location (mm)"] == point1[3]
        xyz_matched_points = df_points[x_matched & y_matched & z_matched]
        assert len(xyz_matched_points) == 1
        point2 = xyz_matched_points.iloc[0]

        # voltage.append(point1, point2, point3, point4)  # This can't be right.
        voltage.append([point1, point2, point3, point4])
    return voltage
```

Note that since you did not provide us with any data to test, this is just a reimplementation of your function, and I have not checked if it meets all your requirements (except for the execution time).

Also note that if this is not fast enough for you, I recommend using KDTree which can handle point clouds more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I think this should be good enough to meet my needs, and I will learn about KDTree.